# Automatically recalculating in ArcGIS Desktop if Excel data source modified?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, excel, table

There's a database with buildings. Each of them has a few parameters, for example building type codes. In a distinct table each building type codes has 4 attributes. 
During the Join, the datas will be connected to the buildings, according to the code.

The problem is if I modify something in the linked Excel table (the secondly mentioned table), the computation should be automatically refreshed based on the new values. (just like in the case of Excel functions)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93733/automatically-recalculating-in-arcgis-desktop-if-excel-data-source-modified/247740#comment131016_93733):

> It might be worth noting that ArcMap caches table information to speed
>   up refresh. I have noticed similar happening before where the data
>   edited in the related table is modified but not reloaded. You can try
>   'reload cache' on the table view, 'save edits' if you are editing but
>   apart from that I don't think there is a way to get around the table
>   caching behavior except for closing and reopening the document.